# Insert into sql column more than 8000 chars with line breaks in java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

how to insert data into one column in MS-SQL more than 8000 chars with line breaks using java?

I have a software list from `psinfo` - sorting and converting arraylist to string with StringBuilder and replacing `\n` with `"' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + '"`

I can insert all text with around 15000 chars without `CHAR 10` and `CHAR 13` but I cannot insert it with new lines, it's inserting only around 8000 chars.

Do you know where is the problem?

I have field software as VARCHAR(MAX)

I have this statement:
`stmt.executeUpdate(... "',software= CAST('" + software + "' AS varchar(MAX))...);`

Comment: Why not leave it \n? :) it should work

Comment: That looks like its a non-parameterized query - can you confirm?

Comment: You should use a PreparedStatement. Don't pass literals like that embedded in the SQL string

Comment: Its output of psinfo from sysinternals, so numbers, letters, anything - VARCHAR... Is it possible to do it like "preparedStatement.setString(X, "my 15 000 chars softwarestring with CHAR10 and CHAR 13 as line breaks");" ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a `PreparedStatement`:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("... software=? ...");
stmt.setString(index, veryLongStringWithNewlines);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

This will avoid any issues with characters in the string that conflict with the SQL dialect's syntax for string literals.

(I couldn't figure out what the `CAST ... AS` would achieve, so I left it out.  I'm guessing it was an attempt to deal with the string length or the embedded newlines or something.)

Comment: I will rewrite all as preparedstatement. It looks better as i looked on code. Thank you for advance.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend to, instead of creating such an SQL expression, add the newlines directly to the string in the Java code and use the result in a parametrized query. To solve this problem and to avoid other problems.

But I was interested in the "why" of this case and did a little testing.

The problem seems to be caused by an implicit cast due to the `+` string operator. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#result-types) state, that the type with the highest precedence of those types from the operands is returned.

If only `varchar(n)` operands are included, the operation apparently returns a `varchar(m)` but no `varchar(max)`. The [maximum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments) for `m` is `8000`. So the data gets truncated if the result is actually longer than 8000 characters.

`+` needs to "see" at least one `varchar(max)` amongst the operands to return `varchar(max)`.

```
SELECT '<put 8000 a's here>' + 'b'
```

results in `'<put 8000 a's here>'` (without the `'b'`), whereas

```
SELECT '<put 8000 a's here>c' + 'b'
```

results in `'<put 8000 a's here>cb'`.

To get a result of `varchar(max)` it's enough to give `+` one such operand, possibly by `convert()`.

```
SELECT '<put 8000 a's here>' + convert(varchar(max), 'b')
```

results in `'<put 8000 a's here>b'`, as expected.

So as the lines in the string from the Java program likely never exceeded 8000 characters in length, the `+` operation gave a `varchar(8000)`, whereas the whole string, without any operation on it exceeded the 8000 character boundary and was implicitly seen as `varchar(max)` by SQL Server. That's why all of a sudden the program broke.